# Why does Bragg peak exist for protons?

Tags: particle-physics, scattering-cross-section, protons

I am doing some research on proton therapy and I don’t understand why a Bragg  peak exists. From Wikipedia, it says that

> A peak occurs because the interaction cross section increases as the charged particle's energy decreases. Energy lost by charged particles is inversely proportional to the square of their velocity, which explains the peak occurring just before the particle comes to a complete stop.

I understand why stopping power is inversely proportional to square of velocity (explained by the Bethe Bloche formula), but I don’t understand how the cross section is related to particle energy. Does stopping power increases because cross section increases? Why does cross section increase?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Remember there are two components of stopping - one is interaction with the electrons (large number of small energy transfers) and the other is interaction with nuclei (few number of large energy transfers). Now consider the form of the Rutherford cross section.

Comment: @JonCuster sorry I still don’t quite understand, could you explain in more detail? How is Rutherford cross section related to this? I am not knowledgeable in this topic.

Comment: maybe this article, found by search, will help https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0031-9155/60/8/R155